# Magento Error: Controller file was loaded but class does not exist

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried with [official website](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) and [Alan Storm's tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world). I created simple test project to display "Hello world".But when i tried to ran it it gives me this "There has been an error processing your request".

I tried to search it gave suggestions to do this
- check class name of the controller. but it didn't work for me.

Getting this error

```
Controller file was loaded but class does not exist

Trace:  
#0:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(326): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')  
#1:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(293): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('/Users/bhavesht...', 'Magentotutorial...')  
#2:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(196): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Magentotutorial...', 'foo')
#3:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6:/Users/bhaveshthakrar/Documents/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7:{main}
```

Let me know if you need code. I am not adding because i followed first tutorial and my code is same is their 's. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by appending `<?php` at the beginning of the controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in /path_to_your_magento/var/report
It contains reports with errors you admit

Comment: I edited question. Let me know if you know what the problem is.